# Encrypting Before Factory Reset

Tags: windows-10, encryption, bitlocker

I heard you should encrypt your data prior to resetting your Windows PC to factory settings (in preparation for selling). However, my Surface Pro 3 (Windows 10) won't let me reset when Bitlocker is turned on.

So I turned Bitlocker off, which I believe unencrypted my previously encrypted data, and now it will let me reset, but I'm worried my data can be found if a hacker gets their hands on it.

Can someone help me with a series of steps to make sure my data is encrypted and then how to factory reset with the data still encrypted?

Comment: Usually you reinstall Windows by using a installation USB stick. Boot from it and you can simply delete the old partition if it is bitlocker encrypted or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cipher](https://www.howtogeek.com/137108/how-securely-overwrite-free-space-in-windows/) or other 3rd party tools to wipe the empty parts of a drive. If it is a SSD, you really need to use the manufacturer's disk utilities to make sure the drive is properly wiped, as sections of the disk can be inaccessible due to overprovisioning.